# Ashynchronous Multithreaded

Tags: java

I have a centralized socket class which is responsible for sending and retrieving data. I have 2 classes:

- one which listens to the input stream and
- the other one which takes care of writing to it.

Listening running on an infinite loop and then process the messages. For synchronous i block the read and reset these values once i receive the response from the server.

Now i am stuck with asycnhronous. I have 3 methods in my service.

1. getSomething
2. readSomething
3. saySomething.

In my `getSomething` i want to implement async functionality based on the boolean flag provided. When my app starts i also start both of my threads and if i send concurrent request.

For example `readSomething` first and then `getSomething` then i get the return value for `readSomething` in `getSomething` which is not what i desire and i can see in the logs that the output for `getSomething` comes after a while.

It looks like the Future object requires to submit a new task which will run in it's own thread but the way i have design this app, i just can't create a new thread. Can anyone give me insights on how should i handle this asycnhronous like a flow chart etc ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing work Asynchronously, that means that other part of the application does not care *when* the async work is done.

What you'll normally want to do is notify the other part, when the async work is done. For this, you'll want to use the ["Observer Pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (the article includes flow-charts).

The basic idea is, that your app starts the async work and is notified, when the work is done. That way, you can loosely couple two parts of the application. A quick example:

```
/**
 * The observer
 */
public interface AsyncWorkDoneListener{

    /**
     * This method will be called when the async-thread is
     *  done.
     */
    public void done(Object unit);

}

/**
 * The worker (which does the asyc-work on another thread).
 */
public class AsyncWorker{

    private AsyncWorkDoneListener listener;

    /**
     * Set (you might want to maintain a list here) the current
     *  listener for this "AsyncWorker".
     */
    public void setListener(AsyncWorkDoneListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Will do the async-work
     */
    public void doWork(){
        // Do the work in another thread...
        // When done, notify the registered listener with the
        //  result of the async work:
        this.listener.done(the_object_containing_the_result);
    }
}

/**
 * The application
 */
public class App implements AsyncWorkDoneListener{

    public void someMethod(){
        // Work on something asynchronously:
        mAsyncWorker.setListener(this);
        mAsyncWorker.doWork();
    }

    @Override
    public void done(Object unit){
        // The asyc work has finished, do something with
        //  the result in "unit".
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of insights:

- you need [dataflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming), not flow charts
- if you cannot create new thread for each task, you can use fixed-sized thread pool created by `java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`
- you cannot use Future.get() from within a task running in a threadpool, or thread starvation deadlock may occur.
- your description of the problem is unclear: too many undeclared notions. "reset these values" - what values? "3 methods in my service" - is it server side or client-side? "boolean flag provided" - do we need to understand who provided that flag and what does it mean?
  Please provide a dataflow representation of the program you need to implement in order we could help you.